# Different versions of the same app on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

So lets say I make a game and I need to have 2 versions of it on the app store. First version is free but with ads, second version would be for those that hate ads; pay lets say 1$ and get a version with no ads.(there would be no other differences in this case, content, gamplay, bug fixes, etc.)
I've checked google and found all sorts of posts, some claimed you can't, others said that option exists "now", yet others that the option was removed, etc. I'm confused.

Can I do this? And if so how, are there any tutorials out there? I'd like details please.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: There are countless examples of apps that do this. So yes, it can be done. But just use IAP (in-app purchase) instead. That way you have one app and a user can choose to pay to remove the ads from the free app.

Comment: Great, that sounds to be exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can. It will considered as another app, with a specific identifier on the App Store.